# Redirect from HTTPS to HTTP in Joomla 3.x

Tags: php, joomla

I have website which works good as HTTP and HTTPS. Now I want to redirect HTTPS to HTTP. I put rewrite rule into .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

but this doesn't work. In my index.php file i put code as below:

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") {
$url = "http://mysite.pl/pl/";
header("Location: $url");
exit;
} 

?>
```

This also doesn't work. Please help me what should I do?
Thank you.

Comment: curiosity to know did u include "RewriteEngine On" in htaccess

Comment: of course, I did

Comment: when I clean my cache and write down http://mysite.pl website load as HTTP, but when I type https://mysite.pl page is loaded as HTTPS and when I don't clean my cache and type http://mysite.pl page redirects me to HTTPS

Comment: if u r using Windows OS.. in run/cmd execute    ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: but I'd like to none of visitors has https page, and I'd like set redirection globally.

Comment: It may be prob only for u

Comment: I've done it but with no success. Still the page redirects to https

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the [global configuration](https://docs.joomla.org/Help38:Site_Global_Configuration) .
Also see [htaccess examples (security)](https://docs.joomla.org/Htaccess_examples_(security))

Answer (score 0):

Try this for .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !protected [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Source: https://www.yellowwebmonkey.com/developer-blog/item/all-the-joomla-htaccess-redirects-you-will-ever-need